# Expo print not functional since update to SDK 49

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, sdk

My expo print worked very well on my React Native expo project with SDK 48.

Since I updated my expo project from SDK 48 to SDK 49 the update was done but my expo print no longer works even though I did not change the code in any way. I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Orientation' of undefined, js engine: hermes
```

Here are my functions that run expo print in my project:

```
const printAbac = async () => {
    await Print.printAsync({
        html: isoSheet,
        printerUrl: selectedPrinter?.url, 
        orientation: Print.Orientation.portrait
    });
};

const printToFile = async () => {
     const { uri } = await Print.printToFileAsync({ html });
     await shareAsync(uri, {UTI: '.pdf', mimeType: 'application/pdf' });
};

const selectPrinter = async () => {
     const printer = await Print.selectPrinterAsync(); 
     setSelectedPrinter(printer);
};
```